# Что за метка [simple-draw]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Есть такая метка [simple-draw](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simple-draw). Имелось в виду "простое рисование"? Зачем она нужна?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это такая библиотека для Python: https://github.com/suguby/simple_draw

На это как бы намекает строка импорта в вопросах по этой метке:

```
import simple_draw as sd
```

Добавил базовое описание для метки.